# Split Listview into two equal halves in order to show 2 items per screen when scrolling - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout, mpandroidchart

I am trying to divide a linear layout into two equal halves.
The main activity is like below. It contains a listview which is populated with an adapter and with two types of chart (MPAndroidChart library).

Main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res

    /android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewChart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1" >
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below are the 2 charts that are used to populate de listview. In the top half is the line chart and in the bottom half is the bar chart.

Line chart:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".50"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Bar chart:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".50"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the weight like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="2">

   <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure to use `0dp` as height for the childs and give them a weight

Comment: Not working for me. Error thrown: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0. Note that the two charts are encapsulated into the listview. I think this is the problem...

Comment: and why are you encapsulating these views in the listview?

Comment: I need a listview and inside it I add its rows using an adapter. Each row, in this case, two rows, is a different type of chart but listview can contain more than two charts so this is the reason I encapsulate into a listview, also to let user scroll vertically to see the different kind of charts in the same screen. I want to show 2 charts per listview page, so I want to split screen into 2 equal parts.

Comment: maybe the correct question from my part will be: how to set the number of desired items displayed in a listview where number can be 1, 2, 3, and so on...but all the listview rows with the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello world"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="goodbye world"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

in the above xml it will calculates total weight that is 2. then i will makes the linearlayout 2(sum of weights) equal parts.

i hope it will help you.